# Using Ubuntu One in Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-one

I've been an Ubuntu user for some time but now looking at moving to a KDE desktop and thinking about installing Kubuntu on my newly rebuilt laptop, however I have an Ubuntu One account and use it a great deal. From what I've been reading there are problems running the Ubuntu One client on Kubuntu, therefore am I better off installing Ubuntu (12.10) and simply adding the KDE desktop afterwards? Would my Ubuntu One client still function in the KDE environment???

Any help appreciated!

Fozzit

Comment: Ubuntu One was closed down so no use in leaving support questions open.

Answer (score 1):

There are no big problems using Ubuntu One in KUbuntu, except missing file manager integration (which is not all that necessary).

You may want to run "ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --with-icon --minimized" when you login to get a nice tray icon, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in that case I am okay to go ahead and install Kubuntu? Is the Ubuntu One client included or do I have to add it separately? Hence my dilemma of whether to install Kubuntu or Ubuntu (which includes the Ubuntu One client) then add the KDE desktop?

Comment: I would install kubuntu and then add ubuntu one if needed, since it's about 300MB smaller than the other way around ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are plug-ins for adding U1 integration as a Dolphin Service Menu. U1 runs just fine on Kubuntu.